# Unable to read lumen log file on centos server

Tags: lumen

Hi  I have setup the lumen application for API. And yesterday I have setup CentOS server. Code is working on my ubuntu server but not working CentOS server. I am getting this response from server :

`The stream or file \"/var/www/html/api/storage/logs/lumen.log\" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chmod 777 your-lumen-project/storage/logs/lumen.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change ownership of storage folder.
On ubuntu run this

```
sudo chown -R {current user}:www-data storage
```

Ubuntu:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage
sudo chown -R ubuntu:www-data storage
```

Cent OS:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache storage
sudo chown -R {your centos user}:apache storage
```